# Can't access lists within objects in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple application in which I want to be able to add texts organized in texts, sentences and tokens. Each text contains a number of sentences, and each sentence contains a number of tokens. My classes look like this:

```
class Text:
    sentences = []

    def __init__(self, meta):
        self.meta = meta

    def getSentences(self):
        return self.sentences

    def addSentence(self, s):
        self.sentences.append(s)

class Sentence:
    tokens = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getTokens(self):
        return self.tokens

    def addToken(self, t):
        self.tokens.append(t)

class Token:
    def __init__(self, word, pos):
        self.word = word
        self.pos = pos

    def getWord(self):
        return self.word

    def getpos(self):
        return self.pos
```

I then create a token, a sentence and a text like this:

```
token = Token("a", "b")
sent = Sentence()
sent.addToken(token)
txt = Text("meta")
txt.addSentence(sent)
```

Now, when I want to access that token, i.e. the first token of the first sentence of the first text, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
print txt.getSentences[0].getTokens[0]
```

... which doesn't work at all. I can access the getSentences method like this

```
 print txt.getSentences
```

which gives me this

```
 <bound method Text.getSentences of <txt.Text instance at 0x1006d5a70>>
```

Comment: You can't call `self.sentences`.  Your sentences list is not an instance variable since you are not defining it in your init.  You are using it as a class variable, use: `Text.sentences`.

Comment: in each class, the list that contain the elements aren't instance attributes, but `class attributes` instead. Move them inside `__init__` (e.g. `self.tokens = []` )

Comment: @Scott that is incorrect: `self.attribute` reaches the variable, but it does not belong to the object instance but to the class instead. So it is shared among each object of the class.

Comment: I've put my lists within __init__ now, but I still don't get how I can access the tokens. "print txt.getSentences()[0]" for example gives me "<txt.Sentence instance at 0x1006d5a28>".

Comment: What are you trying to print? Word or pos? You can do `print txt.getSentences()[0].getTokens()[0].getWord()` which prints `a`.  Or you can add a method to Token: `def __str__(self): return "word:{}, pos: {}".format(self.word, self.pos)` so that you can print the entire token: `print txt.getSentences()[0].getTokens()[0]` prints: `word:a, pos: b`.  But it's not clear what you are trying to get as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with your code.

First, you are defining `sentences` and `tokens` as class variables

```
>>> class Test:
...     myvar = []
... 
>>> 
>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t1.myvar.append(10)
[10]
>>> t2 = Test()
>>> print(t2.myvar)
[10]
```

You should initialize these variables in `__init__`

Second, in python functions are called with `()` operator, just referring to a function name returns function object.

```
>>> def myfunc():
...     print("hello,world!")
... 
>>> yourfunc = myfunc
>>> yourfunc()
hello,world!
```

In the case of using variable sentences you can access it directly with `txt.sentences`, there's no private/public method distinction in python, well there are names with `_`-under and `__`-dunder prefixes, but that's  convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print txt.getSentences()[0].getTokens()[0]
```

This should return the lists instead of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

As additional note: to give yours class the behavior of MyInstance[0], like with list, you have to define the special method

```
__getitem__
```